# Drupal 8 - url to image

Tags: 8

I can't find how to get image url. I have images in /themes/custom/mytheme/img directory. I think there must be some way to get path to current theme or somethink like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `{{ directory }}` for the path to your theme. Then you just need to add /img/yourimage.jpg.

Comment: it outputs as relative path (without leading /), is it right?